# Не могу понять, как изменить цвет определенных букв в input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Я создаю приложение на vue, похожее на тренировку слепой печати. Есть какой-либо сгенерированный текст и input для пользователя. Идет проверка, равняется ли введенный символ символу под таким же номером в данном тексте. Если нет, то нужно подкрашивать данную букву.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="userInput">
  </div>
</template>

data() {
    return {
      text: 'Здесь нужный текст',
      userInput: '',
    }
```

с помощью вотчера проверяю на изменения в инпуте:

```
watch: {
  userInput(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      let index = this.userInput.indexOf(this.userInput[this.userInput.length-1])
      if (this.userInput[index] !== this.text[index]) {
         //Здесь нужно изменять цвет неправильной буквы. 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Как, собственно, изменить эту букву?

Answer (score 0):

Перекрасить просто так часть текста в `input` не выйдет - текст лежит внутри `shadowRoot`, а у `input` нет возможности прочитать и/или изменить `shadowRoot`.

Для создания необходимого вам функционала почитайте как устроены `wysiwyg` редакторы.

Comment: Сделайте переиспользуемый Свой Input, через DIV с нужными emit на события, и тогда!....
сможете "хоть слона обернуть в покрывало".

Comment: @Михаил, слон очень не понравится ни разработчику, ни пользователю, ни гуглу, ни скринридерам - никому. Не надо так